# Invalid customer address id

Tags: magento2.3.2, customer-address, checkout-page

I am getting an issue like Invalid customer address id at

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Invalid
>   customer address id 57 at
>   vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:79

Please let me know the exact reason for this issue.Sometimes my credentials work fine, sometimes getting issue while checkout.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked it further and fixed this issue by overriding Magento's validateForCart function.

```
/**
 * Validate address to be used for cart.
 *
 * @param CartInterface $cart
 * @param AddressInterface $address
 * @return void
 */
public function validateForCart(CartInterface $cart, AddressInterface $address)
{
    $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomer()->getId() ? $cart->getCustomer()->getId() : null);
}
```

The issue is with the customer Id passing in the function is null for the customers facing this issue.